# iruby kernel can't install rbczmq

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu

Just installed the iRuby kernel following the istructions but when i do `jupyter-notebook` command and start a new notebook kernel dies and there is a problem reported on the terminal about libczmq:

```
[I 18:05:11.900 NotebookApp] Kernel started: bcb56cdd-964a-4dae-8a40-76dbcbe7e418

WARNING: ::CZMQ::FFI is not available without libczmq.

Unable to load this gem. The libzmq library (or DLL) could not be found.
If this is a Windows platform, make sure libzmq.dll is on the PATH.
If the DLL was built with mingw, make sure the other two dependent DLLs,
libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll and libstdc++6.dll, are also on the PATH.
For non-Windows platforms, make sure libzmq is located in this search path:
["/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-rzmq-core-1.0.6/lib/ffi-rzmq-core/../../ext/libzmq.so", "/home/randomx/anaconda3/bin/libzmq.so", "/home/randomx/bin/libzmq.so", "/home/randomx/.local/bin/libzmq.so", "/usr/local/sbin/libzmq.so", "/usr/local/bin/libzmq.so", "/usr/sbin/libzmq.so", "/usr/bin/libzmq.so", "/sbin/libzmq.so", "/bin/libzmq.so", "/usr/games/libzmq.so", "/usr/local/games/libzmq.so", "/snap/bin/libzmq.so", "/usr/lib/libzmq.so", "/usr/local/lib/libzmq.so", "/opt/local/lib/libzmq.so", "/usr/lib64/libzmq.so"]
You should install cztop, rbczmq or ffi_rzmq before running iruby notebook. See README.
F, [2017-03-26T18:05:12.031981 #13088] FATAL -- : Kernel died: uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/iruby-0.3/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/iruby-0.3/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/iruby-0.3/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/iruby-0.3/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/iruby-0.3/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/iruby-0.3/lib/iruby/kernel.rb:18:in `initialize': uninitialized constant IRuby::Kernel::Session (NameError)
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/iruby-0.3/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `new'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/iruby-0.3/lib/iruby/command.rb:70:in `run_kernel'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/iruby-0.3/lib/iruby/command.rb:34:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/iruby-0.3/bin/iruby:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
[I 18:05:14.903 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)

WARNING: ::CZMQ::FFI is not available without libczmq.
```

So I installed cztop and ffi_rzmq but when i go to install rbczmq I got an error install message like this:

```
    config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating src/libczmq.pc
config.status: creating addons/Makefile
config.status: creating src/platform.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
"make all && make install"
Making all in src
make[1]: ingresso nella directory "/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/czmq/src"
make  all-am
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/czmq/src"
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE  -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zauth.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zauth.Tpo -c -o zauth.lo zauth.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zauth.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zauth.Tpo -c zauth.c -o zauth.o
mv -f .deps/zauth.Tpo .deps/zauth.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE  -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zbeacon.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zbeacon.Tpo -c -o zbeacon.lo zbeacon.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zbeacon.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zbeacon.Tpo -c zbeacon.c -o zbeacon.o
mv -f .deps/zbeacon.Tpo .deps/zbeacon.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE  -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zcert.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zcert.Tpo -c -o zcert.lo zcert.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zcert.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zcert.Tpo -c zcert.c -o zcert.o
mv -f .deps/zcert.Tpo .deps/zcert.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE  -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zcertstore.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zcertstore.Tpo -c -o zcertstore.lo zcertstore.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zcertstore.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zcertstore.Tpo -c zcertstore.c -o zcertstore.o
mv -f .deps/zcertstore.Tpo .deps/zcertstore.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE  -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zchunk.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zchunk.Tpo -c -o zchunk.lo zchunk.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zchunk.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zchunk.Tpo -c zchunk.c -o zchunk.o
mv -f .deps/zchunk.Tpo .deps/zchunk.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE  -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zclock.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zclock.Tpo -c -o zclock.lo zclock.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zclock.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zclock.Tpo -c zclock.c -o zclock.o
mv -f .deps/zclock.Tpo .deps/zclock.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE  -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zconfig.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zconfig.Tpo -c -o zconfig.lo zconfig.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zconfig.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zconfig.Tpo -c zconfig.c -o zconfig.o
mv -f .deps/zconfig.Tpo .deps/zconfig.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE  -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zctx.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zctx.Tpo -c -o zctx.lo zctx.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zctx.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zctx.Tpo -c zctx.c -o zctx.o
mv -f .deps/zctx.Tpo .deps/zctx.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE  -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zdir.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zdir.Tpo -c -o zdir.lo zdir.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -g -I/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/rbczmq/dst/include -g -fPIC -MT zdir.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/zdir.Tpo -c zdir.c -o zdir.o
zdir.c: In function ‘zdir_new’:
zdir.c:156:9: error: ‘readdir_r’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
         int rc = readdir_r (handle, entry, &result);
         ^~~
In file included from ../include/czmq_prelude.h:257:0,
                 from ../include/czmq.h:31,
                 from zdir.c:35:
/usr/include/dirent.h:183:12: note: declared here
 extern int readdir_r (DIR *__restrict __dirp,
            ^~~~~~~~~
zdir.c:159:13: error: ‘readdir_r’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
             rc = readdir_r (handle, entry, &result);
             ^~
In file included from ../include/czmq_prelude.h:257:0,
                 from ../include/czmq.h:31,
                 from zdir.c:35:
/usr/include/dirent.h:183:12: note: declared here
 extern int readdir_r (DIR *__restrict __dirp,
            ^~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:774: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "zdir.lo" non riuscito
make[2]: *** [zdir.lo] Errore 1
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/czmq/src"
Makefile:586: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "all" non riuscito
make[1]: *** [all] Errore 2
make[1]: uscita dalla directory "/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rbczmq-1.7.9/ext/czmq/src"
Makefile:414: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "all-recursive" non riuscito
make: *** [all-recursive] Errore 1
CZMQ compile error!
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.3
        --with-system-libs
        --without-system-libs
        --with-system-libs
        --without-system-libs

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

I also have installed `libtool autogen autoconf automake` but installation fails anyway..I got the last version of Kubuntu as os
What can I do? Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I had to install the zeromq source from here
http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software